# RegionPlot, RegionPlot3D and differing embedding dimensions

Tags: bugs, regions

`RegionPlot` seems to be for plotting regions with an embedding dimensions of 2 only, and `RegionPlot3D` for regions with an embedding dimensions of 3.

Yet passing a region of the wrong embedding dimension to them might do a number of different thing (which is never an error message complaining about the dimension).

Often they just give an `nnregion` error:

```
reg1 = ImplicitRegion[x^4 + y^4 + z^4 < 1, {x, y, z}]; (* note 3D region *)

RegionPlot[reg1] (* used with 2D plotting function *)

During evaluation of RegionPlot::nnregion: ImplicitRegion[x^4+y^4+z^4<1,{x,y,z}] cannot be automatically discretized. >>

During evaluation of RegionPlot::invplotreg: {ImplicitRegion[x^4+y^4+z^4<1,{x,y,z}]} is not a valid region to plot. >>

(* RegionPlot[reg1] *)
```

(Of course `RegionPlot3D[reg1]` works.)

But look:

```
RegionPlot[Ball[]] (* my understanding was that Ball[] is a 3D region equivalent to Ball[{0,0,0}] *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Even though:

```
RegionEmbeddingDimension@Ball[]
(* 3 *)
```

`RegionPlot[Ball[{0, 0, 0}]` does the same thing.

This works as expected:

```
RegionPlot[Ball[{0, 0}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

(Although weirdly the `BoundaryStyle` option of `RegionPlot` is not respected, perhaps a bug?)

`RegionPlot3D` will also issue an `nnregion` message usually, but not always:

```
RegionPlot3D@InfiniteLine[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Once again the embedding dimension didn't match, but the function just produced an empty plot instead.

---

**Question:**

- Are these all bugs or do some of the results (e.g. `RegionPlot[Ball[]]`) make sense?
- Why don't the functions just check the `RegionEmbeddingDimensions` and let the user know what's wrong?  Is there any technical limitation to this (such as excessive computation time in edge cases)?

Comment: Yes, I think there is room for improvement here, and I've seen similar bug reports from @rcollyer a while ago. It's not utterly unreasonable to give up on plotting with a message (even if not the *best* one) when the available methods fail. For 3D graphics primitives, it looks like `RegionPlot` will try to plot the part in the $xy-$plane, e.g. `RegionPlot[Simplex[3]]` (except the boundary curve isn't shown...), and for `Ball[]` I would have expected the cross-section to have a filled interior... Perhaps some day `RegionPlot` and `RegionPlot3D` will get officially documented for region input.

Comment: @ilian I never realized that `RegionPlot` wasn't documented for region input.  Many of the region types are illustrated through `RegionPlot` in the documentation.

Comment: Right, I meant on `ref/RegionPlot` and not through ad hoc use.